# Should we burninate the sqlmigrations?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

There is a small tag [sqlmigrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlmigrations) that has had some activity on it, with one question asked in May at the latest. Its summary suggests that it should be merged into the [ef-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-migrations) tag, but looking at the question history it appears that a number of questions were about various different technologies to do migrations with sql, that will not have answers that are applicable to each other.

Should we move the few EF specific questions to [ef-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-migrations) and then burn the tag?

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be merged, the tag sqlmigrations is too general and can be applied to other languages and frameworks even.

Once it's removed, if it pops up again, hopefully it will do so with a much clearer tag wiki.